# Mobile - API server security

Tags: api, security, mobile, oauth

I am building an Android app - a key part of which will include integration with a server API.  The app is just a side-project and I am really just looking for validation of my planned API security and suggestions of best practice and how other apps do it.

The application will be mobile only (to start with, no website) - I want to be able to create user accounts from the app, and once signed up, use the central web API to access/update secured user-specific content.

What I have started looking at is a basic hosted MVC web app (I'm JVM/Spring background, so will likely use those libraries, but the question here is tech agnostic) - the app will have no webpages and just expose a series of endpoints:

- Publicly accessible POST endpoints to sign-up & sign-in
- OAuth secured endpoints for user specific content (plus of course the normal OAuth dance endpoints needed)

Is that a reasonable approach? Does using OAuth make sense when I have control over the client and server sides?

I assume the official Twitter app just uses OAuth with its API that it exposes to other users? And Instagram was launched as mobile only platform at first, so I assume they must have had in app account creation & then some API security?

(I know there are further considerations/requirements - communication over ssl, protecting your applications oauth key from people de-compiling the application and then using the key in other apps etc, but really I just want some higher-level input if people have implemented these kind of systems before with success/problems etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good, but any token-based sessions would work. Don't store the credentials (at least not the password) on the device. Only store the token, which can be expired, and store it securely. Require HTTPS and use certificate pinning to prevent session hijacking.

Comment: Great - I am something of a security architecture beginner - what kind of thing do you mean by other token-based approaches? are there any particular alternatives you would suggest.  Also, when you say dont store credentials - I assume you mean user password for account - I won't be able to avoid storing the user accesstoken etc on the device (assuming an oauth solution).  As mentioned, have read a lot about the headaches of storing application oauth API key in the app as it can be decompiled.

Comment: would love to read/hear about how folk like instagram did this (they were mobile first right?) - not found anything that goes in to a lot of details about this yet though

Comment: As far as token based sessions, there are PHP sessions for one. Storing user id and token is fine, but don't store password on device.