# Angular 6 Spring Boot POST Issue

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to set up an angular 6 application that talks to a local spring boot REST application.

I have finally been able to login, and use GET requests, which seem to use the correct cookies. There are 2 cookies, a JSESSION cookie, and a XSRF cookie. The issue is I am getting a 403 response from any POST request. I am pretty confident that it is more of an issue with my Spring set up.

Spring Security config:

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "*")
        .exposedHeaders("Set-Cookie","Authorization");
}
```

And

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .cors()
     .and()
        .httpBasic()
     .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/", "/main", "/user", "/runtime.js","/polyfills.js",
                  "/main.js", "/styles.js", "/vendor.js").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
        .csrf()

.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
     .and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).and()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

}
```

Please note the antMatchers besides "/user" aren't actually being used in this set up. Those files are being served locally using ng serve.

My angular set up:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
{
    const xhr = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'),
        withCredentials: true
      });
      return next.handle(xhr);
}
```

This call will work now:

```
getExercise(id:Number): Observable<Exercise>
{
    return this.http.get<Exercise>(environment.baseUrl + '/api/exercise/' + id);
}
```

But this one, a POST, will not.

```
saveExercise(exercise: Exercise): Observable<Exercise>
{
   return this.http.post<Exercise>(environment.baseUrl + 
   '/newExercise',exercise);
}
```

Spring Security logs for the GET:

```
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@29dbd699
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2de4577a
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@29dbd699
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@29dbd699
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@84a2a85a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/exercise/2' doesn't match 'POST /logout
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/main'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/user'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/runtime.js'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/polyfills.js'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/main.js'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/styles.js'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/exercise/2'; against '/vendor.js'
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/exercise/2; Attributes: [authenticated]
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@74ead523, returned: 1
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/exercise/2 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
Getting exercise by ID: 2
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select exercise0_.id as id1_0_0_, exercise0_.instructions as instruct2_0_0_, exercise0_.name as name3_0_0_ from operation_movement.exercises exercise0_ where exercise0_.id=?
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select goaltypes0_.exercise_id as exercise1_1_0_, goaltypes0_.goal_types_id as goal_typ2_1_0_, goaltype1_.id as id1_2_1_, goaltype1_.name as name2_2_1_ from operation_movement.exercises_goal_types goaltypes0_ inner join operation_movement.goaltypes goaltype1_ on goaltypes0_.goal_types_id=goaltype1_.id where goaltypes0_.exercise_id=?
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2de4577a
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@29dbd699
```

Spring logs for the POST which returns a 403 response:

```
DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /newExercise at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /newExercise at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@84a2a85a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /newExercise at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /newExercise at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /newExercise at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/newExercise
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2de4577a
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@29dbd699
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@84a2a85a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/main'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/user'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/runtime.js'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/polyfills.js'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/main.js'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/styles.js'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/vendor.js'
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /error; Attributes: [authenticated]
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@84a2a85a: Principal: com.op.movement.model.ApplicationUserDetails@7b5de4fa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@74ead523, returned: 1
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
 DEBUG 18776 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Try "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE"  instead of  ("GET", "POST", "*")

Comment: could it be because you are posting to /newExercise and that is not mentioned in the authenticatedRequests?

Comment: also annotate your CORSConfig class with @order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It doesn't seem like these solutions fix the problem though. Using the full list of actions actually somehow broke the OPTIONS requests. I was thinking it would have something to do with the filter order, but setting the CORSConfig order didn't seem to fix it...

Comment: @Taranjit Kang - No, if you are referring to the snippet of code 
    .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/", "/main", "/user", "/runtime.js","/polyfills.js",
                  "/main.js", "/styles.js", "/vendor.js").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()    ------- this is basically telling spring security that those resources are already authorized, and can be loaded by anybody. All other requests should be authenticated. And /newExercise should be authenticated.

Answer (score 6):

For any one having the same issue, doing

```
csrf().disable()
```

will fix this, though I have no idea why. It seems as spring CSRF and CORS clash in some way when using cookies...

If I had to guess, the below is not working as expected

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

which is strange because it makes direct reference to Angular:

```
A CsrfTokenRepository that persists the CSRF token in a cookie named "XSRF-TOKEN" and
reads from the header "X-XSRF-TOKEN" following the conventions of AngularJS. When 
using with AngularJS be sure to use withHttpOnlyFalse().
```

The above seems to be true - I see that the CSRF token is set and sent by the browser, but Spring is not accepting it as valid. (see logs above)

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/newExercise


Request Cookies                         
JSESSIONID  31AD5A7891F8BB83072BFC040AABBB35        
XSRF-TOKEN  579db734-412c-4ce8-82a2-20aa097e47f
```

For now, disabling CSRF will work for development, but there is a real world use case for serving my angular app from a separate server, which is the ONLY server that should be able to make requests to my spring server. Hopefully the additional information can help someone, and I will try to post a real answer here if I ever find it.

Comment: Is this a problem with Angular 6 only?

Comment: @john          I'm not sure - angular 6 is the only version I'm comfortable with. I'm actually not sure it's an issue with angular at all. It could be a spring issue.

Comment: weird... Here .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse just works for GET operations...

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your `.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())` with `csrfTokenRepository` and `CsrfFilter`:

```
 .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

See [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241354/http-status-403-invalid-csrf-token-9ee6949c-c5dc-4d4b-9d55-46b75abc2994-was)

> ```
> @Override
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
> http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
>     .antMatchers("/send-pin").permitAll() 
>     .antMatchers("/check-pin").permitAll()
>     .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/someotherrurl") 
>     .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
>     .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
>     .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
> ```